# HTML box formatting

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, format

So I have this bit of JavaScript code that will create two new input fields each time a button is clicked, right now they show up kinda funny. I attached a picture below. The code is also below. I want the name field to show up aligned wit the top of the bigger box, is there any way to do this?

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "<b>Checkpoint " + markerId + ":</b> <input type='text' id=" + markerId + " placeholder='Checkpoint name'> <textarea rows='5' cols='40' id=" + markerId + "desc> Checkpoint description </textarea> <button type='submit' value='Remove' onClick='remove_checkpoint();' /> <br />";
document.getElementById("divForms").appendChild(div);
```

Thanks!

[image: Picture:]

Comment: are you styling with CSS?  If so, please show code.  If not, look into CSS styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can do this way:

In CSS:

```
textarea {vertical-align: top;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/xPmY2/

---

Or if you don't prefer using CSS, give the style inline this way:

```
<textarea style="vertical-align: top;">Checkpoint description</textarea>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/xPmY2/1/

---

But I suggest you go with the CSS version as inline styles are clumsy.

**Screenshot**

[image]